# What might be the reason why some images in ejs get loaded on the browser why others do not?

Tags: css, node.js, express, bootstrap-4, ejs

The `css`, `js` and image directories are in public directory. In turn, the public directory is inside of views (I don't know if it's a good practice to add public directory inside of views directory).
The `css` files and the `js` files(in the public directory) are working but only one of the images (that is, the logo at the `navbar` section) gets loaded on the browser whenever I start up the server, the remaining images are showing little icons in there respective positions. All the images are in the same directory and  I linked all of them in the same manner. Why is it that only one is appearing on the browser?
I don't know if it's a good practice to add the public directory inside of views directory, but when I added both on same path with `app.js`, all the files in public stopped working. But I know I'm on the wrong track because of the following reasons:

1. No difference is observed whether
   app.use(express.static("public"); is added to ```` app.js``` (that is, the server file) or not. This means that that line of code is not working, still the ```` css`and`js` files work in both cases.
2. Only one of the images is being displayed on the browser even if all are linked in the same way.
3. The word public appears in the source of each of the static files, omitting it stops all the static files from working.

App structure:
med,
`webapp,`
main,
views,
partials
`footer.ejs`
`header.ejs`
public
bootstrap
`css`
`js`
images
`home.ejs`
`post.ejs`
`news.ejs`
`about.ejs`
`contact.ejs`
`app.js`
`package.json`

I hope indentation will help here since I'm not allowed to post pics yet.
The images in home.ejs are
`img src="../views/public/images/syringe-pill-capsule.jpg,`
`img src="../views/public/images/dna-1811955_1920.jpg",`
`img src="../views/public/images/lab-217043_1280.jpg".`
the only one that is loading on the browser is the logo at the navbar section,in header.ejs. The link is img src="../public/images/wd.jpg"

Comment: Can you add some of your code? E.g. how you've embedded the image links in your template and the relevant parts of your `app.js`?

Comment: I just edited the question, please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing the correct path to express.static. You need to change the root to the actual root, i.e.:

`app.use(express.static("./path-to-views/public")`

Then, you need to make sure to use the correct paths in your html, which will be as simple as:

`src="/images/syringe-pill-capsule.jpg"`

---

EDIT:

The root for `express.static` you were using is correct, i.e.
`app.use(express.static("views")`

But you need to adjust the paths in the images `src` attributes to the following absolute path:
`src="/public/images/syringe-pill-capsule.jpg"`

Comment: I made all the adjustments, still the images did not load on the browser. The presence or absence of `app.use(express.static("./path-to-views/public")` did not still have any effect in the functionality of the application whenever I start up the server

Comment: I hope you did not actually use `/path-to-views/public`?! You need to replace it with the actual path. In your case probably `app.use(express.static("./views/public"))` ...

Comment: The one that worked for other static files is `app.use(express.static("views")));`. But since the images, css files and js are in the same directory (called views) aren't the images supposed to load  since css files, js files and images are all static files?

Comment: Ah I see, try to change the image paths to absolute urls then: `src="/public/images/syringe-pill-capsule.jpg`

Comment: Thanks a lot. All the the images are loading now

Comment: Please recap because I'm new here

Comment: @ChukwuyemObiazi: Next to my answer on the left there' s a checkmark symbol. Please click it and my answer will be accepted.

Comment: I just did that, check if it has been accepted, or is there anything I need to do on the page I'm redirected?

Comment: Hm no, seems it didn't work. Where are you being redirected to? As far as I know there should not happen any redirect when clicking the checkmark symbol.

Comment: Oh, it seems I clicked on the wrong thing. You meant the checkmark below the trianglar shapes used for voting, right?